# Is there a way to group cases which refer to the same issue together?

Tags: case, performance, email2case

Currently the salesforce set-up is creating a case every time a client enters live chat, emails in to a support email and then a sales email. If a user communicates via all 3 channels regarding the same issue, salesforce is creating multiple case records in the system. Is there a way to consolidate the cases created together?

Answer (score 2):

You create (or designate) one case as the "parent" case, and the other cases become child cases of that case. Use the Parent Case field to associate cases together. You can also choose to [Merge Cases](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cases_set_up_lex_case_merge.htm&type=5) if you desire. Both are viable options.

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast response! Let me try this out and see if it resolves the issue.